# polarssl-dev - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I would like to install polarssl-dev for Ubuntu 14.04 from their repositories.  I read this was available in universe on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/polarssl  but I enabled universe including src, and it was not there. How could I do this?

`# apt-get install polarssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package polarssl-dev`

`# grep univer /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse`

If somebody would not mind telling how I went wrong, I'd be really grateful.

Kind regards, Soph.

Answer (score 0):

The package names for PolarSSL actually start with lib. This should work for you:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpolarssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpolarssl5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpolarssl-dev libpolarssl5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 459 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,962 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libpolarssl5 amd64 1.3.4-1 [186 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libpolarssl-dev amd64 1.3.4-1 [274 kB]
Fetched 459 kB in 6s (71.3 kB/s)                                               
Selecting previously unselected package libpolarssl5.
(Reading database ... 61244 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpolarssl5_1.3.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpolarssl5 (1.3.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpolarssl-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libpolarssl-dev_1.3.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpolarssl-dev (1.3.4-1) ...
Setting up libpolarssl5 (1.3.4-1) ...
Setting up libpolarssl-dev (1.3.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```